# How to remove a Page Break in a .docx file that was converted from an .odt file?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, openoffice

I recently converted an OpenOffice .odt (word-processing) file to an MS Word 2010 (.docx) file.  The .odt document contained a page break.  The page break appears in the .docx file in MS Word, but after an exhaustive effort (and Google search), I can find no way to remove the page break from the .docx document through MS Word.

I can add new page breaks from within MS Word (and remove them) just fine - it's just this one page break that was imported from the .odt file that I cannot remove.

Can someone please tell me how to remove the page break that was imported from the .odt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning on paragraph marks. You then may be able to see and delete the page break.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/show-or-hide-formatting-marks-HA010102250.aspx

Comment: Sadly, this does not work.  I do exactly as the link states - View -> Paragraph -> Show Paragraph Marks ... and I see paragraph marks throughout the document - but there's no visible mark for the page break, and no way to select and delete it.

Comment: Maybe you can delete it with another program. Try re-opening in open office or google docs?

Comment: I opened with Google Docs, saved in Google Doc format, then downloaded as Word format, and it worked.  Thanks.