# How to find and remove implicit page break in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In Word 2010 style formatting, just before one of my level 2 numbered heading (not before the others, at least before most of them), I get a page break that is invisible in the paragraph marks view. I used an old document as a template, so I inherited this from template, but when I ctrl + c it to another document, this setting will get migrated as well. It looks very similar to the result desired in [another question](https://superuser.com/q/524319/373304), but the script view (after alt + F11) shows nothing. A comment under a [vaguely related answer](https://superuser.com/a/309864/373304) suggests opening it in another program, but it seems the document wasn't ever touched by OpenOffice, which shows even less page breaks than MS Word. I didn't try XML view, [it shouldn't work anyway](http://www.codegur.press/24720972/finding-implicit-page-break-in-word-document-using-xml-parsing). I also checked all the paragraphs around the break, but none of them had "Page Break Before" checked.

I can think of one workaround: to remove and rebuild all the formatting. This seems like a lot of work, so is it possible to remove these hidden page break in any easier way?

My workaround: I copied this to another file, deleted the paragraph before, copied it there again, just without few last chars which I wrote again by hand, and the page break disappeared. I copied whole document content back and it seems to work. But this is not reliable.

Comment: I've read your question and I'm quite confused:( Please consolidate it and instead of a chronological order, summarize the useful information you have, some screenshots could be useful as well. Generally page breaks in Word are driven by: manual page break characters or various paragraph settings: "page break before", "keep with next", "keep lines together". Especially the second one can cause strange layout if it's on for several paragraphs after each other. Have you checked those?

Comment: Check paragraph settings/formatting. You most likely tiked the "page break before" option (can't tell how it's actually named right now).

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I checked "page break before" before, but not the other ones. Now I disabled all the settings you mentioned off in the whole document and the problem is solved. Please expand your comment into answer, it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally page breaks in Word are driven by:

- manual page break characters:

[image]

- or various paragraph settings:

  - "page break before"
  - "keep with next" Especially this one can cause strange layout if it's on for several paragraphs after each other.
  - "keep lines together".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'd try to remove all formatting: select all,in the font group choose the option clear all formatting.
This should remove all formatting that is applied on paragraph level or on text level.
If this solves your problem; search more on there; if it doesn't solve your problem, try selecting all tekst (do this manually and omit the very last paragraph mark) and paste it in a new document; did that help?

I'm also thinking you have different page sizes, f.e. page one is A4 and page two is A5. But I believe you should see section breaks inbetween.